# SQL Server stack trace for a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, input, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to see all the input values passed into a particular user-defined stored procedure to SQL Server.  I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.  Sometimes I don’t have access to the client code that calls this procedure, and the bug is likely inside the procedure, therefore, I want to know when and what the input values my procedure executes with.   If this information, I can debug the procedure without running the whole complicated process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Profiler will give you this information.  You need ALTER TRACE permissions on the database to run Profiler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

In addition to the Start Menu link, you can run it from the "Tools" menu in SQL Server Management Studio.